# Running periodic tasks in Dart and Flutter in background even if app is closed

Tags: android, dart, flutter

What I'm trying to do is every like 1 min or so connect to REST API get all pending push notifications from database and if time matches time on the device send a push notification. I can't use Firebase for that because I was told to use only self-hosted Services. I found a plugin that should do the thing with running tasks in the background [android_alarm_manager 0.2.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager#-readme-tab-)

The problem is that it depends on [Firebase_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) plugin which requires to connect my app to Firebase.

Is there any equivalent of this plugin that would let me run background tasks without the need to connect it to Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the native android service which runs for every one minute then on first launch of your flutter app through `platform channel` you call the service. using `shared preference` you can make that platform channel service call only on first time app launch.

Comment: how about iOS? as far as i know, there is a limitation on iOS